# Nowhere complex analytic function except one point.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$f(z)=f(x+iy)=xy+iy$$ Show that $f$ is nowhere analytic.

Obviously all partials are existent and continous everywhere.

To satisfy Cauch-Rieamann conditions, $x=0,y=1$.

But if I were to take limit (limit definition of the derivative)

I found that it is exists and equal to one as expected at $(0,1)$ $f'(i)=1$

Question: Since I can find the derivative of $f$ at $(0,1)=i$, doesnot it mean that there must be some neigborhood that $f$ is analytic there? (since it is differentiable at (0,1))

Comment: No. The good result is that if $f$ is $\mathbb{C}-$differentiable on an open set $U$, then $f$ is analytic on $U$. This does not apply if $U$ is not open.

Comment: When you say you calculated the limit, what _exactly_ did you do?

Comment: *"If a function is holomorphic at a point, the function is holomorphic in a neighborhood"* is a true statement, but be careful; we *define* a function to be holomorphic at a point exactly when it is complex differentiable in a neighborhood of that point. Complex differentiability at a point does not imply complex differentiability in a neighborhood, as $z \mapsto |z|^2$ shows. What this means is that the Cauchy-Riemann equations at a single point do not entirely capture holomorphicity, and a bit more care is needed